# C++: unique_ptr polymorphism for template classes derived from a non-template base class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have the following class:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() = default;
    virtual ~Base() {};
}
```

And, let's say I have a unique_ptr to this class, aka:

```
using BasePtr = std::unique_ptr<Base>;
```

Now, let's assume I have a template class that inherits from the base class.

```
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Base {
public:
      Derived() = default;
      Derived(const T x) : some_variable(x) {};
      ~Derived() override {};
       void hello() { std::cout << some_variable << std::endl; }
 private:
       T some_variable;
}
```

For arguments sake, let's say I have a factory method that creates a unique_ptr to some new instance, such as:

```
template <typename T>
auto make_class(const T& x) -> BasePtr {
    return std::unique_ptr<Derived<T> >(new Derived<T>(x));
}
```

If I try to build this:

```
int main() {
    auto ptr = make_class<int>(5);
    if (ptr) {
         ptr->hello();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With C++11, this results in a compile error (saying that Base does not have a hello() method), because it seems that the actual instance stored in the unique_ptr is a Base, not a Derived.

Based on my understanding (at least if Derived wasn't templated), this should not be an issue. What's happening here?

Comment: `make_class` returns a pointer to `Base` (that's what you declared it to do) - the `unique_ptr` doesn't change that

Comment: The templating makes no difference, `Base` doesn't have a function called `hello` and your assumption is wrong (which you could have tested by the way)

Comment: Then your understanding is not right. Your `unique_prt<Base>` has a `Derived` instance in it. That does not mean that you can call `Derived`s methods from it. You can only access the `Base` methods.

Comment: Could someone explain how to make his code work?

Answer (score 0):

You function `make_class` returns a `BasePtr`:

> auto make_class(const T& x) -> BasePtr

Then in your `main` function you say:

> auto ptr = make_class(5);

that is, `ptr` is a `BasePtr`. The function cannot know that the pointer actually points to a derived class. For this reason, there is no `hello()` function that could be invoked.